# How can I use the latest version of the d3 js library with Angular Dart?

Tags: angular, d3.js, dart

My goal is to create a simple Angular Dart program that uses the latest version of d3 js https://github.com/d3/d3/. I am having difficulty creating the latest version of the library. **What is the correct way to use the d3 js library in Dart?**

Here is what I tried:

The d3 Dart package from dartlang is from 2015. I want the latest version so this is no good. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/d3

I tried going to definitely typed so I can get a typescript file to convert to a dart file using dart_js_facade_gen. https://github.com/dart-lang/js_facade_gen

d3 definitely typed github: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/d3
In the d3 path, there is an index.d.ts file. I copied only that file locally and ran this command:

```
dart_js_facade_gen index.d.ts
```

and recieved the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dart_js_facade_gen/index.js:11
  if (e.name !== 'DartFacadeError') throw e;
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isExternalLibraryImport' of undefined
    at resolvedPath.forEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dart_js_facade_gen/build/lib/main.js:90:31)
...
```

Comment: Have you followed this thread on the loader error:?https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/586 Several possible culprits are in there.

Comment: That issue does not seem relevant. Let me try to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to use javascript libraries, I should just use Angular Typescript. It seems like Angular Dart is in its own bubble.